# Corollary of Riemann Roch theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, schemes, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I'm studying about Riemann Roch theorem for curves and its consequences (in algebaic gemoetry).

In Hartshorne I've found an exercise equivalent to this assert:

> Let $D$ be an effective divisor of a curve $X$ of genus $g$, prove
>   that $h^0(D) \leq deg \,D$.

Is easy to prove it in the case of special divisors, but how to prove the assert if $deg \, D \leq 2g-2$?

Thank you for help!

Comment: It's $h^0(D)-1$ — the dimension of the associated complete linear system!

Comment: No, Joseph's claimed inequality **is** correct for $g\gt 0$.

Comment: Dear @GeorgesElencwajg, this extra assumption doesn't show up in the question. Reading the question I was a little confused because of the two obvious counter-examples and when I found the corresponding Hartshorne exercise, I thought it was just a typo. Maybe I was a little quick. In the inequality I've shown, equality holds precisely for $g=0$ or $ D=0$. From this the claimed inequality follows for all the remaining cases. I will add the details tomorrow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface and $D$ an effective divisor on $X$. Then $h^0(D)-1 \leq \mathrm{deg}(D)$.

Let $g$ be the genus of $X$. Since $D$ is effective, $h^0(K_X-D)\leq h^0(K_X) = g$. From this and Riemann-Roch we directly get the claimed inequality $$h^0(D) - 1  = \mathrm{deg}(D)-g+h^0(K_X-D)\leq \mathrm{deg}(D).\quad (*)$$

Addendum, in reaction to Georges Elencwajg's comments:

> The inequality $h^0(D)\leq \mathrm{deg}(D)$ holds if and only if $D>0$ or $g\geq 1$.

In fact, it suffices to prove that in $(*)$, equality holds if and only if $D = 0$ or $g = 0$. Apparently, equality in $(*)$ is equivalent to $h^0(K_X-D) = g$.
If $g = 0$ or $D = 0$, then this equality is easy to see.
The other way around suppose $g>0$ and $D>0$.
Then $h^0(\mathcal{O}_X(K_X)\otimes\mathcal{O}_D)> 0$.
Thus, from the long exact sequence associated with the exact sequence $$0\to\mathcal{O}_X(K_X-D)\to\mathcal{O}_X(K_X)\to\mathcal{O}_X(K_X)\otimes\mathcal{O}_D\to 0$$ we get $h^0(K_X-D) < h^0(K_X) = g$.

(This now makes a complete solution to Hartshorne's exercise IV 1.5.)

Comment: If the map $H^0(\mathcal{O}(K_X)\otimes \mathcal{O}_D)\rightarrow H^1(\mathcal{O}_X(K_X-D))$ is injective, then we actually don't the result we want. Can we ensure this doesn't happen? (Maybe some vanishing theorem?)

Comment: Dear @NathanLowry, if $g>0$, then $K_X$ is base-point free. Hence, for any $p\in\mathrm{Supp}(D)$, the restriction map $H^0(K_X)\to H^0(K_X|_p)$ is surjective. Since it factors through the restriction $H^0(K_X)\to H^0(K_X|_D)$, the latter map has to be non-trivial. That’s enough to ensure the claimed inequality. (Since it’s been a while, I don’t recall if that’s the argument I had in mind back then, or even if it’s in the scope of knowledge assumed in the question.)

Comment: Dear @Ben, could you explain why $h^0(K_X-D)\leq h^0(K_X)$ holds for effective divisor $D$? Thanks.

Comment: Dear @Ang, the inclusion $\mathcal O_X(K_X-D)\to \mathcal O_X(K_X)$ induces an injective map on global sections. Taking dimensions gives $h^0(K_X-D)\leq h^0(K_X)$.

Comment: nice.  note also that if deg(D) = d, the linear system |D| is contained in the d-fold symmetric product of X, hence has dimension ≤ d.  If equality holds, then all effective divisors of degree d are linearly equivalent, hence so are all effective divisors of degree one, so X equals the projective line.

Answer (score 4):

Let $D$ be an effective divisor of degree $d$ on the smooth projective curve $X$ over the algebraically closed field $k$.
If $D=0$ it is clear that $H^0(X,\mathcal O(D))=k $ so that taking dimension we have $l(D)=1$.
If  $\operatorname {deg} D=1$ then $D=1.P$ for some $P\in X$ and $H^0(X,\mathcal O(D))=k $ so that $l(D)=1$,
 *unless* $X=\mathbb P^1$ in which case $l(D)=2$.
And now it is smooth sailing thanks to the exact sequence

> $$0\to H^0(X,\mathcal O(D-P))\to H^0(X,\mathcal O(D)) \to \mathcal O(D)\mid_P \;\cong k\to 0             $$

where the last non trivial map is evaluation at $P$.
This exact sequence yields $l(D)\leq l(D-P)+1$ from which we deduce by complete induction and the preliminary analysis above that for $\operatorname {deg}(D)\gt 0 $ :

> $$l(D)\leq \operatorname {deg}(D) \quad \operatorname  {if}    X\ncong \mathbb P^1   $$

and recall that in the remaining case  we have :

> $$ l(D)= \operatorname {deg}(D)+1 \quad \operatorname  {if}    X\cong \mathbb P^1                $$

**Note carefully**
The above proof requires essentially only the definitions but not the notion of genus and even less the knowledge of Riemann-Roch.
Notice also that we get (if  $X\ncong \mathbb P^1$  ) $l(D)\leq \operatorname {deg}(D)$ and not the weaker result $l(D)\leq \operatorname {deg}(D)+1$ sometimes found in textbooks .

Comment: It's nice to see that this can be done without Riemann-Roch! (Even though the question was about Riemann-Roch, really.)

Comment: Dear Ben, it is quite natural to use Riemann-Roch in that context and I did that too when I first learned the theory. It is  a strange phenomenon that sometimes easy proofs come only after one has struggled with  more advanced theories. Another example is the  invocation of Hilbert's Nullstellensatz for results which only depend on basic definitions: I constantly see  excellent algebraic geometers do that on this site and elsewhere. But even if  elementary proofs exist, it is perfectly legitimate to post, as you did,  more sophisticated ones, as confirmed by the OP's  accepting your proof

Comment: The exact sequence gives $l(D)=l(D-P)+1$, but we also have $l(P)=1$, so you really proved $l(D)=\text{deg}D$ for any $D>0$ if $X$ is not isomorphic to projective line. Is this right?